# raise ValueError('Filename must be a string') ValueError: Filename must be a string when upload file to AWS S3 in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have used Django to develop a web app.
In the frontend, the user is supposed to upload an image by upload button to AWS S3.
But I got the error at s3_client.upload_file:

```
        raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

view.py

```
def save_pic(request):
print("save_pic")
if request.method == 'POST':
    image = request.FILES.get('image')
    print(image)

    img_name = image.name


    ext = os.path.splitext(img_name)[1]


    img_path = os.path.join(settings.IMG_UPLOAD, img_name)
    with open(img_path, 'ab') as fp:

        for chunk in image.chunks():
            fp.write(chunk)

    import boto3
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='XXX',
aws_secret_access_key='XXX', region_name='XXX')
    try:
   
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as fp:
            response = s3_client.upload_file(fp, 'etp-tms', 'image_0.jpg')
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)


    try:
        data = {'state': 1}
    except:
        data = {'state': 0}

    return JsonResponse(data)
return JsonResponse(data="fail", safe=False)
```

HTML：

```
    function renderCover(value, row) {
        return '<input id="image-input" accept="image/*" type="file" />\n' +
            '<img id="image-img" /> '
    }

        function upload() {
        //alert("upload");
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("image", $("#image-input")[0].files[0]);
        formdata.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken",$("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val());
        $.ajax({
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            url:'/save_pic/',
            type:'post',
            data:formdata,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (arg) {
                if (arg.state == 1){
                    alert('success')
                }else {
                    alert('fail')
                }
            },error: function () {
                alert("error")
            }

        })
    }
```

when I upload the img， the error occurs at response = s3_client.upload_file(fp, 'etp-tms', 'image_0.jpg').:

```
    raise ValueError('Filename must be a string')
ValueError: Filename must be a string
```

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html
according to the docs, you don't need to open the file, just get the file name and put it in. In your case, your method should be upload_fileobj. There are 2 examples in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file), the function `upload_file` has three required arguments:
`filename`, `bucket`, `object`.

All of them are strings.

Your `fp` object is not a filename, and it's not a string. Pass the filename to the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you already opened the file, use [`upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)

```
with open(img_path, 'rb') as fp:
    response = s3_client.upload_fileobj(fp, 'etp-tms', 'image_0.jpg')
```

Otherwise, stop opening the file yourself and simply use [`upload_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(img_path, 'etp-tms', 'image_0.jpg')
```